# Groovy DSL: setting properties in closure

Tags: groovy, dictionary, dsl, ternary-operator

I want to implement an 'active' flag for rules in my DSL. Here's how I wanted it to look like:

```
Shipping("Standard") {
    active: true
    description: "some text"

    rules {
      ... define rules here
    }
}
```

Here's how I got everything running following several tutorials:

```
Script dslScript = new GroovyShell().parse(new File("Standard"))

dslScript.metaClass.Shipping = { String name, Closure cl ->
  ShippingDelegate delegate = new ShippingDelegate()
  delegate.name = name
  cl.delegate = delegate
  cl.setResolveStrategy Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  cl()
}

dslScript.run()
```

ShippingDelegate is simple:

```
class ShippingDelegate {

  String name

  void rules(Closure cl) {
    ... do stuff here
  }
}
```

It all runs fine without complaints but how can I access 'active' or 'description'?

What does this syntax actually do anyway? It looks like a map assignment, but there is none. Or does the groovy compiler treat it as an incomplete ternary operator?

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest a small change in your DSL so that your design can be simplified?

**Edited, it is not clear in you example if you have more than one shipping instance. In my second try, I assume that the answer is yes**

```
class ShippingRules {
    boolean active
    String description
    String name


    ShippingRules(String name) {
        this.name=name
    }

    def rules(Closure c) {
        c.delegate=this
        c()
    }
}



abstract class ShippingRulesScript extends Script {
    def shipppingRules =[]

    def shipping(String name, Closure c) {
        def newRules=new ShippingRules(name)
        shipppingRules << newRules
        c.delegate=newRules
        c()
    }
}

def cfg= new CompilerConfiguration(
    scriptBaseClass:ShippingRulesScript.name
)
Script dslScript = new GroovyShell(cfg).parse(new File("Standard"))

dslScript.run()
```

The DSL should be changed to this:

```
shipping("Standard") {
    active= true
    description= "some text"

    rules {
      ... define rules here
    }
}
shipping("International") {
    active= true
    description= "some text"

    rules {
      ... define rules here
    }
}
```

I.e. lose the capital to shipping, and use assignments instead of colons.

You would then later be able to retrieve the shipping rules from your dslScript shippingRules variable.

**disclaimer:** I cannot test my code right now, so there may be some typos in the code, but you get the general idea: use a base class where you provide your rules and properties to your script.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was aware only of using ExpandoMetaClass to attach global functions to the Script's environment but this abstract class extension is much more easier and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on Google+, see [here](https://plus.google.com/117783247727182623015/posts/9qjU7nR6gsU).
The summary is: you can use the map syntax only on constructors (ctors) and as function parameters.

Interesting is that it doesn't throw an exception.